# form data saved in localstorage and post to php

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I am working on a simple login form for a mobile site that will save the form data in local storage but will also post data to a php file for url redirection with appended form data. I need help as the storage is working but the post for this is not. 
Html

```
<form class="form-signin" action="siteurl/processing/login-app.php" method="post">
     <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
 <input type="text" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Eventname" id='eventname'>
 <input type="text" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Username" id='username'>
 <input type="password" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Password" id="password">
 <label class="checkbox">
 <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me" id="remember_me"> Remember me
 </label>
 <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="submit">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

Now the script

```
    <script>
        $(function() {

            if (localStorage.chkbx && localStorage.chkbx != '') {
                $('#remember_me').attr('checked', 'checked');
                $('#username').val(localStorage.usrname);
                $('#pass').val(localStorage.pass);
            } else {
                $('#remember_me').removeAttr('checked');
                $('#username').val('');
                $('#pass').val('');
            }

            $('#remember_me').click(function() {

                if ($('#remember_me').is(':checked')) {
                    // save username and password
                    localStorage.usrname = $('#username').val();
                    localStorage.pass = $('#pass').val();
                    localStorage.chkbx = $('#remember_me').val();
                } else {
                    localStorage.usrname = '';
                    localStorage.pass = '';
                    localStorage.chkbx = '';
                }
            });
});




    </script>
```

And the php

```
<?php

    if (isset($_POST["eventname"]) && isset($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["password"])) {

        $eventname = $_POST["eventname"];
        $username = $_POST["username"];
        $password = $_POST["password"];

        $url = "siteurl/index.php/$eventname?user=$username&passw=$password";


       header( "Location: $url" ) ;

    } else {

       echo "Username and Password not found"; 

    }

?>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You are handling the checkbox click event, whereas you probably want to be handling the form submit event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your POST variables work off the input names, not ids.
Add a name attribute to your inputs and access them.

Comment: Thank you. Been look at this way to hard.

Comment: It happens. I usually go outside for 20-30 mins to help me see the nuances like that.